trying to run my flutter app and i it Failed to build iOS app on flutter
trying to my flutter app and i keep getting
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           32.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/chat_board/ios/bundle identifier/Info.plist'. Did you forget to
declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

flutter clean
flutter build ios (this also gave me an error)

also i have my info.plist existing in my ios directory

The Info.plist files seem to be in the wrong place. It is generally in project_name/ios/Runner/Info.plist.
If the Info.plist is in proper place, check where you point you Info.plist path in your ios project. For this open Xcode go to Targets -> Runner -> Build Settings, and search Info.plist file and see if the proper path is given for all schema.


You stated that you have the info.plist file. So what you need to do is to hard clean build folder.

Open your project in xcode (open Runner.xcworkspace in your ios file)
Then in the App Menu select product and while holding Option in your keyboard select Clean Build Folder Immediately



Then run your flutter project again.

